# Bootstrap 3 un collapsing class in error

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3

I've got a weird problem. I'm using Twitter Bootstrap 3, JQuery plus JQuery Validate and Hash to build an accordion menu. In my code I have the following line to collapse a panel:

```
$("#collapseThree").collapse('hide')
```

However the panel is being shown not collapsed. Here's my fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/H7kJ3/

To replicate the issue enter a title and email address then press the "Next" button. The second panel ('Step 2') is correctly opened however panel three ('Step 3') is also opened for some unexplained reason.

Comment: Does the page start with `#step1` in the url? Looks to me like some sort of initialisation problem.

Comment: No the page does not have a #step1 in the url when loading it. Interesting when I do add #step1 to the URL the page is initially incorrectly displayed with the panels for step2 and step3 opened!


`if ( hash == '#step1' ) {

            $("#collapseOne").collapse('show')
            $("#collapseTwo").collapse('hide') 
            $("#collapseThree").collapse('hide')         
            $('#progressbar').css('width', '20%')

}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to switch off toggling.

```
$("#collapseOne").collapse({ toggle: false })
$("#collapseTwo").collapse({ toggle: false })
$("#collapseThree").collapse({ toggle: false })
```

A fork of your code is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/qujck/eyZJv/)